# How do I collect a string from a specific line

Tags: perl, split, substr

I am working with someone else's Perl code, and would like to extract a string from line 2 rather than line 1.

4-line repeats in the below format make up a file to be processed:

```
@HWI-M02096:147:000000000-AFU9U:1:1101:15747:1825 1:N:0:CGTACTAGCTCTCT
CTACAGCAGAGAGTGTTTAGGAAGCACCTTTTCGTTAGGCAGATTT
+
3>AAAFFFFC?FGFGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHGHHGGHHBEFHHH
```

my understanding is that substr offsets by $barcodeLen and records a string of $UMIlen length given on line 1. This is written to a file with output line 1 split at the space between "1825" and "1:N:0" followed by the recorded string 
Ex:
@HWI-M02096:147:000000000-AFU9U:1:1101:15747:1825   TCTCT

```
my $seqdir = $ARGV[0];
my $barcodeLen = $ARGV[1];
my $UMIlen = $ARGV[2];
my @seqfiles = <$seqdir/*>;
foreach my $file (sort@seqfiles) {
       getUmi($file);
}

sub getUmi 
{
    my $seqfile = shift;
    open(INFILE, "$seqfile") || die("Cannot open file $seqfile  $!\n");
    my @temp = split(/\//,$seqfile);    
    my $outfile = $temp[length(@temp)];
    my $outfile1 = "UMI-" . $outfile;
    my ($line, @line, $umi, $firstbps, $seqlen);
    open(OUTFILE1, ">$outfile1") || die("Cannot open file $outfile1 
$!\n");
    my $i =0;
    while (<INFILE>)
    {
        $line = $_;
        chomp $line;
        $i++;
        if ($i % 4 ==1)
        {
              @line = split(" ", $line);    
              @temp = $line[1];
              ### extract umi
              $umi = substr($temp[scalar @temp - 1],$barcodeLen, 
$UMIlen);
              print OUTFILE1 "$line[0]\t$umi\n";
        }
    }
    close(INFILE);
    close(OUTFILE1);
}
```

I am failing to understand the @temp array and the $line variable how these are used to generate the example output. I would like to generate the same sort of output, but instead collecting title information from line 1 "@HWI-M02096:14..." but a string from line 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for `@tmp` -- the statement `@temp = $line[1];` always sets array `@temp`  one element, which is `$line[1]` (second element of `@line`).  That is unneeded -- `$line[1]` a single valued variable (scalar) so assign it to a scalar variable, not array.  Then `$temp[scalar @temp - 1]` is a roundabout way of getting the last element of `@temp`) -- which here can only have exactly one element. (The last element in an array is idiomaticaly `$temp[-1]`, while if one wanted to use the last index value then it's `$temp[$#temp]`)

Comment: Regardless their use of `@temp`, if you need stuff from line 2 it's going to be different. So, what do you need to extract? /// To detect the second line in each group of four note that `if ($i % 4 == 2)` is true on lines 2,6,10,... Or, to get a line after the `@`-line set a flag on lines that start with `@` and then check for it -- which is true right on the next line (where you unset it)

Comment: What does your file look like?  Provide some more lines to understand the format. 

Then share the desired output.

Comment: This code is pretty much a mess. Hardly worth trying to reverse engineer. You need to understand what you're supposed to be doing with the input and rewrite from scratch.